# Yammer API - How to know whether I liked a message, messages.json endpoint

Tags: yammer

I am using messages.json endpoint to show the messages in my website. When looping through this messages.json response, I get
liked_by field that contains a count of total likes on each message/comment, and an array of users that liked the message/comment.
But if the message/comment has more than 4 likes only 3 users are returned. In this users array my name does not appear even if I liked. Is there any way to know whether I liked this message.

I can't call https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/users/liked_message/:Message_id.json API against each message because there is a limit(10 requests in 10 seconds.) in number of calls as per yammer document.

Comment: For as far a I know, there is not other way to do this than by calling the /users/liked_message/:Message_id.json endpoint. In my application, I check for the user_id in the message itself (like you are doing) and skip the message after that if the liked_by count is <= 3. This should speed up you webpage a bit.